# Como faço para um vetor de char reconhecer uma quebra de linha?

Tags: c++

O código tá assim

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    char frase[30];
    
    char j;
    
    int i=0;
    do{
        cin>>j;
        if(j!=' '){
            frase[i]=j;
            i++;
        }
    }while (j!=' ');
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: uma quebra de linha é um caracter escape igual a `\n`, já tentou verificar comparando com isso?

Comment: já, não dá certo

Answer (score 1):

A quebra de linha é um caractere de "escape", são caracteres do tipo "ENTER" ou "TAB". No caso do quebra de linha é o "\n", e pode ser comparada assim `== "\n"`, mas alguns caracteres não é possível pois não tem caracteres de "escape", como o caso de um "DEL" por exemplo, por isso uma forma de cobrir todos os caracteres é converter o um `char` para `int` que vai retornar o código `ASCII`, que será 10 e comparar, assim:

```
int ascii;
....
ascii = (int)frase[i];

if (ascii == 10) // é uma quebra de linha
```

Pode testar com esse pequeno programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

     int ascii, i;
     char texto[] = "Bom dia\nGood Moring\nBonjour";
     
     printf("%s\n------------\n", texto);
     
     for(i=0; texto[i]; i++) {
        ascii = (int)texto[i];

        if (ascii == 10) {
            printf("Quebra de linha\n");
        } else {
            printf("%c = %d\n",texto[i],ascii);
        }
    }
}
```

Ou ver online funcionando aqui: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/0utzo5p

E pode ver a tabela com os outros códigos `ASCII` aqui: https://sites.google.com/a/aebenfica.org/apontamentos-tic/tic/ascii

**OBS**: editei a pergunta baseado nos comentários para refletir melhor a comparação

Comment: muito obrigada..

Comment: se a pergunta foi útil não esqueça de votar e aceitar a resposta se resolveu o problema :)

Comment: A quebra de linha pode ser comparada diretamente como qualquer outro `char`, a conversão para `int` não é necessária. [Aqui](https://ideone.com/6QOzE9) seu código comparando diretamente `texto[i]` com `\n` ao invés de `ascii == 10`.

Comment: sim @JúlioEvêncio mas eu coloquei um exemplo que pode cobrir qualquer caractere com a tabela ASCII sendo mais amplo, e se fosse um caracter sem escape como o símobolo do "ômega"  ou um caracter de "DEL" por exemplo,como vc ia comparar?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Minha observação é sobre sua afirmação de que o caractere "quebra de linha" não se pode comparar diretamente como `char`. De fato há símbolos que não podemos fazer isso, mas esse não é o caso da quebra de linha. Quem ler a sua resposta  pode pensar que não é possível fazer isso `'\n' == texto[i]` para encontrar uma quebra de linha e por isso fiz a observação.

Comment: ok @JúlioEvêncio entendi seu ponto, editei a pergunta colocando essa informação, veja pf. Mas também pense sobre sua afirmação *"A quebra de linha pode ser comparada diretamente como qualquer outro char"*, isso também não está corretos, caracteres que não podem ser digitados e não tenham escape não podem ser comparados da mesma forma que "qualquer outro char" :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual Acho que sua resposta ficou melhor agora. Bem, eu estudo C/C++ há pouco mais de 1 ano e sempre achei que a quebra de linha era um caractere do tipo `char` qualquer e o `\n` era seu símbolo ASCII. Agora eu fiquei na dúvida, há diferença entre `'A' != 'b'` e `'\n' != 'b'`?

Comment: sim, os caracteres chamados "escape" são representações de caracteres que não estão por assim dizer "disponíveis" diretamente no teclado, e são precedidos por barra invertida,  por exemplo  `\n` apasar de serem 2 caracteres, eles contam como 1 e representam o `char` com código ASCII 10, assim como o `\t` representa o TAB, código ASCII 9 e assim por diante. No seu exemplo ambos vão retornar `true` pois  'A' é diferente de ´b´(códigos ASCII 65 e 98 respectivamente) e '\n´diferente de ´b´(códigos 10 e 98). Tabela de "caracter escape": https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape